# How to serve up static images/css/assets in the fluxible template project?

Tags: webpack, fluxible

I'd like to have static assets copied to the build folder as well, things like images and css and assets.

I noticed in their sample project, server.js is mapping the build folder to /public.

`server.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')))`

Should I

a. have webpack copy contents of my public folder into the build folder as part of the build process

b. Or, set up another static route in express pointing to my public folder, -if so the reference to the build folder can be confusing since it has the public name in it as well.

c. a hybrid, add css processing to the webpack step and have the processed css files also go in the build folder, but have static assets like images that are not processed served up in a seperate /assets express.static route.

I'm new to webpack so not sure how to set up a or c so help there would be appreciated.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
                    require.resolve('babel-loader')
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
        ]
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Comment: Did you come to any conclusion? I'm in the exact same situation atm and the more I read, the more confused I get >_<

Comment: Same here. I'd like to see the diff to get from what the template produces to working scss imports. I've found what appear to be solutions but can't see how to relate them to the template.